# How to replace "Open Powershell..." with "Open Command Prompt... context menu when clicking on empty space in folder?

Tags: windows-10

When I click on an empty space in a folder view, I get this menu:

[image]

I'd like to replace `Open PowerShell window` with `Open Command Prompt Here`.  Note, that I am not right-clicking on a folder, but rather on an empty space within a folder.

P.S.  This question is about clicking on an empty space in Explorer, not clicking on a folder.

Comment: See: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-176-CMD-and-PowerShell-Context-Menus

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No, it's not a dup.  This question is about clicking on an empty space in Explorer, not clicking on a folder.

Comment: Its the same thing.

Comment: Have you tried a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+open+command+prompt+here)? If so, what is the inadequacy of the options given?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it is definitely NOT the same thing.  I went through the answer, implemented it and got nothing when right-clicking on an empty space in the folder view.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The problem with all the solutions provided is that they are talking about right-clicking on a folder.  I need a solution for right-clicking on an empty space in the the folder view (like in the image) and getting the `Open Command Prompt here`, like we had in Windows 8 and 7.